# Why doesn't my hide function work on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#promotion_profile_booking_description').keyup(function () {
    var left = 200 - $(this).val().length;
    if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
    }
    $('#counter').text('Characters left: ' + left);
  });
  $('#counter').bind('click', function() {
    (this).hide();
  });
});
```

The previous code essentially inserts "Characters left: x", as a text counter. It works great. However hiding the element on a click is another story. Why isn't my hide function working? Do you see any obvious errors in my JS?

Comment: -1 Because "doesn't work" is an awful error indicator -- SO is already full of too many of these localized questions. Please read the error console and/or perform more debugging as to what "doesn't work".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing `(this).hide();` to `$(this).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Also Use a debugger my friend. It can help allot to figure out you have no errors in the script. With firefox you can easily pop up the javascript debugger by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J.

Comment: This deserves to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm just trying to point you to the desired way of using StackOverflow.  Your post is useful advice, but it's not a direct answer to his question and, as such is more appropriately posted as a comment to his question, not as an answer.  Answers should be actual answers to the question.